# How to set title to the <span>/<div> tag such that it should read <br/> tag in the data and show tooltip in separate lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have below angular js sample code which will read the HTML tag within the data and display the content. Data display on screen like -

**Hi Mike! 

Good Morning!!!**

I have requirement to show the title as per the data display. Such that title/tooltip should also show the content in 2 separate lines (considering **br** within the data. Currently title/tooltip displayed as **Hi Mike! `<br/>` Good Morning!!!** in single line

Sample Code:

> ```
> <html ng-app>
> <head>
>     <title>Sample</title>
>     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.js"
> ```
>
> type="text/javascript">
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>             function SampleCtrl($scope) {
>                 $scope.message = "Hi Mike! <br/> Good Morning!!!"
>             }   
>
>         </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
>         <span title="{{message}}" ng-bind-html-unsafe="message"></span>
>     </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: use a javascript tooltip in a directive, will give you some style flexibility that you don't have using native `title` display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an HTML break, you should be able to use a new line character `\n`. Because the title attribute reads its content as a string, it will not render HTML data.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/tcjbkqqz/

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.message = "Hi Mike!\nGood Morning!!!"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out $sanitize - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

You can use it in a directive to actually render html in model content, rather than just output it as a string.

```
<span ng-bind-html="message"></span>
```

In a recent project where I needed to trust user input, I created a filter using $sce.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

```
.filter('trusthtml', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
})
```

And then, for your example, I would use -

```
<span ng-bind-html="message | trusthtml"></span>
```

What version of angular are you using?  I believe ng-bind-html-unsafe ( the directive you are using ) has been deprecated, and am unable to find documentation on it.

Comment: I think he's asking about the title. Maybe I'm reading wrong, but I don't think that method works for making a title two lines.